# Logicapp_Connection id issue

Tags: json, powershell-2.0, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have tried to deploy the logic app via ARM template, Which is getting deployed successfully, But issue is with the JOB scheduler, which is not picking up in connection id, But the job is getting deployed when I use my credentials but that should not be the case.

**ARM Script for Logic App Deployment**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_logicapp_xyz_name": {
            "defaultValue": " logicapp_xyz ",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_azureautomation_1_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xyz6c051-f4ef-4a30-8ce7-c9fb99ff0xyz/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup-A/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureautomation-123",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_logicapp_xyz_name')]",
            "location": "region",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        "Recurrence": {
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 1
                            },
                            "type": "Recurrence"
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Create_job": {
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "Uri": "http://10.xyz.0.xyz:443/BrowserWeb/servlet/BrowserServlet?,
 http:// 10.xyz.0.xyz:443/BrowserWeb/servlet/BrowserServlet?,    http:// 10.xyz.0.xyz:443/BrowserWeb/servlet/BrowserServlet?"
                                        },
                                        "runOn": "Hybrid_worker-Resourcegroup"
                                    }
                                },
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureautomation']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "put",
                                "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('xyz6c051-f4ef-4a30-8ce7-c9fb99ffxyz')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent('DevOpsTestRG-B')}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent('AAC-SUB-01')}/jobs",
                                "queries": {
                                    "runbookName": "Hybridrunbook-Resourcegroup",
                                    "wait": false,
                                    "x-ms-api-version": "2015-10-31"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "Create_job_2": {
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Create_job": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "configXml": "C://Users/devops/Desktop/ServiceMonitor/xyz_LoginPageMonitorConfig.xml"
                                        },
                                        "runOn": "Hybrid account-Resourcegroup"
                                    }
                                },
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureautomation']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "put",
                                "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('4776c051-f4ef-4a30-8ce7-c9fb99ff0xyz')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent('Resourcegroup-B')}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent('XYZ-SUB-01')}/jobs",
                                "queries": {
                                    "runbookName": "Hybridrunbook-Resource group",
                                    "wait": false,
                                    "x-ms-api-version": "2015-10-31"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "azureautomation": {
                                "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_azureautomation_1_externalid')]",
                                "connectionName": "azureautomation-1",
                                "id": "/subscriptions/4776c051-f4ef-4a30-8ce7-c9fb99ff0xyz/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/managedApis/azureautomation"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is the desired behavior, you need to also script the API connection with credentials to connect to the automation account. The `Export template` won't give you these information as it does not expose credentials....

Answer (score 0):

After deployment, the logic app works end-to-end with valid parameters. However, you must still authorize OAuth connections to generate a valid access token. For automated deployments, you can use a script that consents to each OAuth connection, such as this [example script in the GitHub LogicAppConnectionAuth project](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth). You can also authorize OAuth connections through the Azure portal or in Visual Studio by opening your logic app in the Logic Apps Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You used like `Export template` to get the template just like Thomas said it doesn't contain credentials. And if you deploy to other groups it also doesn't create the API Connection so it won't connect.

So you could [download from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio#download-from-azure), then deploy with this json template, it will contain connection details. I test with Custom deployment, it will detect the API connection.